# Apple Pay vs In App in Dynamic Content

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments, applepay

I am working on an educational app that works just like Udemy. It has got a number of courses, let's assume 100. The Apple development guidelines ask us to use in app purchase but creating 100 purchase packages a gruesome task. I wanted to ask if I can use Apple pay for this since the courses can update any time in the future and the purchase packages will need to be handled manually.
What should be the ideal payment procedure in this case? In-App/Apple Pay/ Payment gateway (Stripe)?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem, since I am also facing this?

Comment: I did ask around but no solid advice was found with a credible source. I am currently using both, will try Apple Pay in the first try and otherwise move to inapp purchase.

Comment: Please update if apple pay option is approved by Apple.